# Accessibility For cellRendererSelector component in AG Grid (Angular)

Tags: angular, accessibility, ag-grid

I need to focus on Link in 'Rendered Value' column with keyboard navigation. Also need to make the click clickable through keyboard control. Example of the requirement is given in 'https://plnkr.co/edit/ocVxn4jjJb4F0zmb?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts'

Lets say there is an AG Grid table (Angular) with first column's cell is rendering using 'cellRendererSelector' property and it renders a component named as 'firstcell.component.ts'

In FirstCellComponent, we have an anchor tag. But when I am navigating using tab key then focus appears on first column's cell only and not inside cell's content that is on anchor tag.

It will be really appreciated if you could help me. Thank you in advance!

I tried with tabIndex and href attribute of anchor tag but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In case you already did this and it's still not working, it's possible that AG-Grid's default keyboard navigation is interfering with your custom keyboard navigation. To disable AG-Grid's default keyboard navigation for this cell, you can create a custom navigation configuration.

Let me give you a hint.

1. Define your custom navigation function. This function will disable keyboard navigation for your cell (or any cell that uses your `firstcell.component.ts` as a renderer).

```
function myCustomNavigation(params) {
  var key = params.event.key;
  var node = params.node;
  var column = params.column;
  var isFirstColumn = column === params.columnApi.getAllDisplayedColumns()[0];

  if (isFirstColumn) {
    switch (key) {
      case 'ArrowUp':
      case 'ArrowDown':
        params.event.stopPropagation();
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

2. Set this function as your grid's navigateToNextCell callback:

```html
<ag-grid-angular
  /* your other grid options */
  [navigateToNextCell]="myCustomNavigation"
></ag-grid-angular>
```

This will prevent AG-Grid from overriding your custom keyboard navigation for the first column.

I hope my approach would be helpful for your case.